# MySQL delete in table problem

Tags: php, mysql

Because I have so many categories, I created a single "categories" database table :

```
"id_category , parent_id , category_name , category_tag"
```

example :

```
  ----------------------------------------------------------
  | id_category | parent_id | category_name | category_tag |
  ----------------------------------------------------------
  | 1           | 0         | Cars          | cars         |
  | 2           | 1         | Parts         | parts        |
  | 3           | 2         | Accesories    | accesories   |
  ----------------------------------------------------------
```

the tree :

```
  Cars
     |_Parts
           |_Accesories
```

My problem occurs when I want to delete all records in the tree.
How do I delete all records in the tree branch from above example.

Is that possible in mySQL with PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

What you're looking for is a foreign key on parent_id that references id_category with constraint ON DELETE CASCADE. Then you can just delete the root element (category_id 0) and you should end up with an empty table.

Answer (score 2):

Look up `InnodB`, that is type of database engine your site is probably using `MyISAM` at the moment, also look up `Cascade Deletes`.

InnobDb lets you assign relationships between indicies in your table, you can then assign an action as to what happens when a row is deleted or updated.

You want to set the `ON DELETE` action to `CASCADE`, this will cascade the delete operation to child rows and their child rows. So deleting a parent will automatically delete all children, grand children, etc.

Comment: I just read mysql doc...Seems is working.Thank you very much for indications.

Answer (score 0):

A database table is not essentially a tree what you would normally do is

```
DELETE FROM categories WHERE id_category=3
```

or

```
DELETE FROM categories WHERE id_category=3 AND parent_id=2
```

Comment: This isn't scalable at all. Avoid.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have key with constraint, you can delete everything just by a TRUNCATE command on the table.

If you do have a key configured for cascade deletion, deleting the top item (parent_id=0) will delete all the depending and subdepending rows. In this case, deleting the first row would empty the table.